# Github API v3: fetch events from since date til date

Tags: github, github-api

Is it possible with Github API v3 to fetch events from since date til date?
Nothing in documentation: http://developer.github.com/v3/events/

Answer (score 3):

You can not specify an end-date, however, since the results are paginated, you can stop requesting events after a certain date on your own.